# Transforming pattern with gsub

Tags: r, regex

Why does this:

`gsub("([0-9])+(e)+(-)","\\1^x10^\\3",eg)`

Turn this:
`eg<-5.4748554e-14`

Into this:

`5.4x10^-14`

I want to make it this:

`5.4748554x10^-14`

Comment: Why not just replace the `e`? ie `sub("e",  " x 10^", eg)`??

Comment: I wanted it to change just the scientific notation e in strings that also contain normal words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `+` inside the parenthesis to make it a single first group match:

```
> gsub("([0-9]+)(e)+(-)", "\\1x10^\\3", eg)
[1] "5.4748554x10^-14"
>
```